Installation of unofficial ROM on Lenovo tablet doesn't finish and device is unusable now
I have an old Lenovo tablet, device model is Lenovo Tab4 8 Plus (TB-8704x). Since it stopped receiving updates after Android 8.0, I wanted to install a more recent version of Android from unofficial builds available.
I have gotten the ROM from following two sources:

Pixel Experience: https://xdaforums.com/t/rom-unofficial-10-0-pixel-experience-10-for-lenovo-tab-4-8-plus-tb8704f-x-n.4221955/
LineagheOS: https://xdaforums.com/t/rom-unofficial-10-0-tbx304f-l-x-lineageos-17-1-for-lenovo-tab4-8-rom-for-the-lenovo-thinkpad-tablet.4259205/.

I have a vague memory of the setup step so I grabbed a few ROMs and compatible TWRP, then I followed the following steps:

Unlock the boot loader from Setting and enable debug mode on device.
Unlock the bootloader using command fastboot oem unlock-go, or it was fastboot oem unlock. I don't remember which one worked exactly but one of these did the job.
Reboot the device in fastboot mode and flash the recovery using following command:
fastboot flash recovery twrp-3.2.3-0-tb_8704x.img. Probably a mistake. Its not required since you can just boot a custom recovery which I did next anyways.
Boot into TWRP using command fastboot boot TWRP-3.4.0-0_TB-8704X.img.
I wiped Cache and Data from Wipe > Advanced Wipe menu in TWRP.
Already inserted was SD card with ZIPs of ROMs above. I selected Install menu and selected only one of the ZIP files to install on my tablet.

TWRP installation screen stays there for hours and installation doesn't finish. I tried with other ZIP as well and same result. On normal reboot of the device its stuck in boot loop.
What can I do to fix this?
foersn

The second post on your first link contains the necessary steps to go back to stock firmware: To install you should be running stock firmware, you can restore using the Lenovo Rescue and Smart Assistant (LMSA) tool on a PC.

@Robert Thanks, I think its in right direction to get my device to at least a working stage. This software is Windows only, but Windows needs driver to work with Android device in fastboot mode, unlike Linux/mac. And googling around I see that each OEM has their custom fastboot drivers, which I am not able to find for Lenovo. Or can I use something which is generic for Android?

For some devices there are special adb drivers (because of the USB ID not covered by the standard adb driver from Android SDK) , but fastboot drivers should be always the same. Just use the one from Android SDK.
